# Accessing form controls during Timer.Elapsed event

Tags: wpf, vb.net, timer

I have a WPF application written in VB.net. I'm trying to access a form control during a timer event, but the code is throwing an exception. Below is my code:

```
Public WithEvents attendanceFetchTimer As System.Timers.Timer

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    attendanceFetchTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(cfgAttFetchInterval)
    AddHandler attendanceFetchTimer.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf getAllDeviceAttendance)
    attendanceFetchTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub getAllDeviceAttendance(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs) Handles attendanceFetchTimer.Elapsed
    If(checkBox1.isChecked) Then 
        'Do something here change the textbox value
        txtStatus1.Text = "Getting Attendance Data Done!"
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is that when I debug, the `checkBox1.isChecked` is showing this message:

> "Cannot evaluate expression because we are stopped in a place where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code of the current method may be optimized."

and in the console this error message is displayed:

> "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll"

The same problem happens when I try to change the text of `txtStatus1`.

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is a very poisonous class, only ever use it when you understand *exactly* what it does.  And what you are doing it not legal, you cannot access UI components in the Elapsed event handler.   Use a DispatcherTimer instead.

Comment: I have closed your question as a duplicate. Please see my answer in the linked question to understand how to properly work with WPF in a multi threaded scenario, using DataBinding. If the linked answer doesn't satisfy your needs, please feel free  to post a new  question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `System.InvalidOperationException` looks like it is caused by cross-thread access to a UI component.  The `System.Timers.Timer` by default fires the `Elapsed` event on a thread pool thread.  Using [`DispatcherTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the `Tick` event will get things on the right thread for accessing the UI in WPF.

It also looks like you may have duplicate event handlers wired up, since you have both `WithEvents`/`Handles` and `AddHandler`, but I'm not entirely sure how that works in WPF.  You probably want something like (untested):

```
Private attendanceFetchTimer As System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer

Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    attendanceFetchTimer = New System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()
    AddHandler attendanceFetchTimer.Tick, AddressOf getAllDeviceAttendance
    attendanceFetchTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(cfgAttFetchInterval)
    attendanceFetchTimer.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub getAllDeviceAttendance(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If(checkBox1.isChecked) Then 
        'Do something here change the textbox value
        txtStatus1.Text = "Getting Attendance Data Done!"
    End If
End Sub
```